# How to convert a cron to a daemon

Tags: shell, unix, cron, daemon, ksh

I have a cron shell script which calls a stored procedure to do some operation. I want to know how can I change that cron to a daemon.

Here's what I have.

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    # @(#)abc.sh    


    . /somedir/env/some_profile
    JOBNAME=`basename $0`
    LOG_DIR=$PROJHOME/log
    LOG_FILE=$LOG_DIR/process_abc.log

    function usage
    {
      echo "${JOBNAME}: Usage: ${JOBNAME}"
      echo "Exiting..."
      echo "process_abc ended ***UNSUCCESSFULLY*** at `date`" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
      echo ""  | tee -a $LOG_FILE
      exit 1
    }
```

Can you please help. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you want this to run more that 1 time, don't  you think you need some sort of looping mechanism? Also, what is wrong with `00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/nomad/bin/myScript ....` ? which would run your job every 10 minutes. Good luck.

Comment: What would the benefit of running that as a daemon be? Also, Oracle has its own scheduler function (DBMS_SCHEDULER) so you don't necessarily need an external process.

Comment: @shellter 
Thanks for your comments, I want it to keep run rather than 10 mins.

Comment: 10 minute increments was an example, you can run it every minute with `0-59 * * * * * ....` . ELSE you need a `while true ; do .... done` loop around your code (plus sleep 1 sec or ?)

Comment: It would really help to edit  your question to include an explanation of why you think this is necessary, and why you don't think a cron job or Oracle DBS_SCHEDULER are sufficent. I know I've read numerous discussions of how to setup daemons here on S.O., but I can't find the one I"m thinking of right now. Searching for `[unix] script to daemon`, most of the posters windup accepting that a cron job is sufficient. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just run it from bash

```
SLEEP_INTERVAL=3600
(echo $$ > /var/run/script-runner.sh.pid && while :; do script.sh ; sleep $SLEEP_INTERVAL ; done) &
```

or you can do the same loop inside the script

```
trap "function_that_runs_everything" HUP
echo $$ > /var/run/script.sh.pid
while :; do
    function_that_runs_everything
    sleep $SLEEP_INTERVAL #or sleep forever just waiting for SIGHUP
done
```

this way you can also force the execution of the internal function from the outside

```
kill -1 `cat /var/run/script.sh.pid`
```

also i would suggest rewriting:

```
if [ `/usr/ucb/ps -auxww | grep $JOBNAME | grep "sh -c" | grep -v grep  | wc -l` -gt 1 ]
```

to use $$ (current shell's pid) and create pid file

```
pseudocode:
PIDFILE=/var/run/`basename $0`.pid
if $PIDFILE exists
    log and exit
else
    echo $$ > $PIDFILE

...
run
...
rm -f $PIDFILE
```

(dont forget to remove the pid file @ failure exits)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just daemonise it using The Fat Controller?

fat-controller.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what a daemon does.  It sits and waits for EVENTS, then responds to them.  This is different from a cron job, which simply runs according to a schedule.

It's very easy to make something that will run, wait for something to happen, do something when it happens, then continue waiting for something to happen again.  All you really need is a wrapper for your existing shell script.  The wrapper needs to recognize the conditions of an *event*, and launch the script you'd otherwise launch in cron.

The wrapper can be as simple as a shell script that gets run by a cron job on the "@reboot" special string (`man 5 crontab` for details).  Run the wrapper script directly, or inside GNU Screen so you can attach to it in the future and see how it's doing (if you didn't include error handling).  To be smart, it should also avoid running your existing script more than once at a time (i.e. give it a lock file), though you're already sort of handling that in your ksh script, above.

Rather than jackdoe's unending loop with sleep, above, you want to recognize an *event* that will trigger your script to run.  For example, should it be run when a file named "somefile" gets uploaded using vsftpd?  Then:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    *UPLOAD*/somefile",*)
      /path/to/abc.sh
      ;;
  esac
done
```

It's a hackish, half-assed solution that doesn't include start/stop functionality, but it'll get you going.

Really, this wrapper should take care of locking to avoid launching abc.sh multiple times, and should maintain its own pid file so it can be killed by a handler in /etc/init.d/ (Linux) or /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ (FreeBSD).